# Why does an exception thrown in Try.recover not break execution flow?

Tags: scala, exception

I've written two functions to illustrate my confusion:

```
import scala.util.Try

def TryRecover: Unit = {
  Try {
    throw new Exception()
  }.recover {
    case e: Exception => {
      println("caught error")
      throw e
    }
  }

  println("got to the end of TryRecover")
}

def tryCatch: Unit = {
  try {
    throw new Exception()
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => {
      println("caught error")
      throw e
    }
  }

  println("got to the end of tryCatch")
}

TryRecover
tryCatch
```

This is the output:

```
caught error
got to the end of TryRecover
caught error
java.lang.Exception at .tryCatch(<console>:13) ... 30 elided
```

I would not have expected "got to the end of TryRecover" to ever be printed. Why does `throw e` in `.recover` not break execution flow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Try.recover`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/6a4c2270201d6c5b5127c9d51fb7614f58897886/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala#L230) executes the passed in partial function argument `pf` inside another try-catch

```
  def recover[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U]): Try[U] = {
    val marker = Statics.pfMarker
    try {
      val v = pf.applyOrElse(exception, (x: Throwable) => marker)
      if (marker ne v.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]) Success(v.asInstanceOf[U]) else this
    } catch { case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e) }
  }
```

so since `e` is being re-thrown by `pf`

```
{ case e: Exception => println("caught error"); throw e }
```

`recover` evaluats to `Failure` value which is just a regular first-class value, that is, execution flow is not broken. In fact, we could say the main purpose of `Try` is to lift unsafe exceptions into regular values such that we do not crash the program exceptionally.

Comment: I guess another way to say it is, "`Try` makes explicit the _implicit_ exceptional return type of any code that could throw an exception." (Excuse the slight abuse of the term "return type".)